# Real-time changing point chart with Google Charts

Tags: javascript, charts, google-visualization

I have a problem with google charts. I have struggled with this problem for two few days now and I can't seem to find a solution.

I'm suppose to create a monitoring system where I can see changing line chart that has two lines in it. I'm generating the data in the JS code (at least for now).

I don't know what I'm doing wrong. I can make the chart visible with really simple static example but as soon as I'm trying to add some data to the chart it stops drawing.

Error with this current version is:

> "uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined"

but this is nth time I have tried different method of adding more data to the chart and also nth different error. 
So if someone knows how adding data to google chart works, it would be great to hear.

Thanks in advance.

```js
setInterval(function() {  
  //this is how I create a random data and call the drawChart function.
  var temperature = (Math.random() * (35 - 30) + 30).toFixed(1),
      humidity = (Math.random() * (40 - 15) + 15).toFixed(1),
      timestamp = new Date();
  google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart(timestamp, temperature, humidity));
}, 5000);

function drawChart(timestamp, temperature, humidity) {
  //Cast temperature to proper format for the chart
  //This works...don't understand why but it does.
  temperature = parseFloat("temperature");
  humidity = parseFloat("humidity");  

  // Define the chart to be drawn.
  var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();

  if (data[0].length == 0) {
    var datetime = new Date();
    data.addColumn('datetime', 'Time');
    data.addColumn('number', 'Temperature');
    data.addColumn('number', 'Humidity');
    data.addRow(datetime, 0, 0);

    var options = {
      'title' : 'Temperature and Humidity',
      hAxis: {title: 'Time'},
      vAxis: {title: 'Temperature and Humidity'},   
      'width':550,
      'height':400   
    };
  }
  data.addRow(timestamp, temperature, humidity);
  // Instantiate and draw the chart.
  var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('monitor-chart'));
  chart.draw(data, options);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"/>
    <title>Projekti 1, sivusto</title>

    <!-- Latest BOOTSTRAP minified CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css"/>

    <!-- jQuery library -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <!-- Latest BOOTSTRAP JC-->
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

    <!-- JS Generate new data Class -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/generate_data.js"></script>

    <!-- GOOGLE CHARTS visualization -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      google.charts.load('current', {packages: ['corechart','line']});  
    </script>

    <!-- My css file -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/ulkoasu.css"/>

  </head>
  <body>
    <article>
      <h1>This is Monitor content</h1>
      <div id="monitor-data"></div>
      <div id="monitor-chart"></div>
    </article>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Nope, it's in the same file atm.

everything is at the end of <body></body> tags.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**first,** the argument for `setOnLoadCallback` should be a reference to a function, like follows...

```
google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
```

not the *result* of a function call...

```
google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart(timestamp, temperature, humidity));
```

**and** `setOnLoadCallback` is typically only used once per page load,
after the callback finishes for the first time, this method is no longer needed

regardless, the `callback` can be added to the `load` statement
`setOnLoadCallback` isn't really needed

---

other errors include the use of `addRow` --> `data.addRow(timestamp, temperature, humidity);`

the column values should be passed in an array...

```
data.addRow([timestamp, temperature, humidity]);
```

---

recommend setup similar to the following -- when the callback fires,
all the resources, such as the chart, options, and data table are created

`drawChart` is simply used to add one row and draw the chart

see following working snippet...

```js
google.charts.load('current', {
  callback: function () {
    var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('monitor-chart'));

    var options = {'title' : 'Temperature and Humidity',
      animation: {
        duration: 1000,
        easing: 'out',
        startup: true
      },
      hAxis: {
        title: 'Time'
      },
      vAxis: {
        title: 'Temperature and Humidity'
      },
      height: 400
    };

    var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
    data.addColumn('datetime', 'Time');
    data.addColumn('number', 'Temperature');
    data.addColumn('number', 'Humidity');

    var formatDate = new google.visualization.DateFormat({pattern: 'hh:mm:ss'});
    var formatNumber = new google.visualization.NumberFormat({pattern: '#,##0.0'});

    getTemp();
    setInterval(getTemp, 5000);
    function getTemp() {
      var temperature = (Math.random() * (35 - 30) + 30);
      var humidity = (Math.random() * (40 - 15) + 15);
      var timestamp = new Date();
      drawChart(timestamp, temperature, humidity);
    }

    function drawChart(timestamp, temperature, humidity) {
      data.addRow([timestamp, temperature, humidity]);

      formatDate.format(data, 0);
      formatNumber.format(data, 1);
      formatNumber.format(data, 2);

      chart.draw(data, options);
    }
  },
  packages:['corechart']
});
```

```html
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div id="monitor-chart"></div>
```

Comment: This is exactly what I wanted to do! Thanks alot!

Still don't understand the first 2 rows, but I think I'll have to google that google.charts.load stuff.

About that data.AddRow thing you said should be in array format..
I read in official documentation that data.AddRows should be in array format but there there was an example where data.AddRow was written like I did in my code. 

I guess there's just a mistake in documentation.

Comment: [`addRow`](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/reference#addrow) takes an array `[col1, col2]` -- [`addRows`](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/reference#DataTable_addRows) takes an array of arrays `[[col1, col2], [col1, col2]]`